# Which one is the correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentence is correct?

(1) What subjects do this semester encompass?

(2) What subjects does this semester encompass?

I think the second one is the correct one. Because if we try to answer this question it would be something like "This semester encompasses the following subjects..." Am I correct?

Any suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why did you use competition instead of semester for an answer?

Comment: Sorry that's my fault @user47014. Will edit soon. Though it doesn't matter. Because both **competition** and **semester** are third person singular numbers and same grammatical rule will be applied for both of them.

Comment: If we answer this question, it will be, "This semester encompasses...." [This semester does encompass...] Que. Does the semester encompass? What does the semester encompass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right and your reasoning is correct. The subject is "semester" and because it is singular it **encompasses**.